# PHP: How to add an extra field and value in this array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array which stores the values to specific fields. What i want to do here is to add an extra field name and value into this array. How can i do it?

```
array_walk($files_data, 'array_sanitize');

        $fields = '`'.implode('` , `', array_keys($files_data)).'`';
        $data = '\''.implode('\', \'',$files_data).'\'';

   mysqli_query($dbCon,"INSERT INTO users_info($fields) VALUES ($data) ");
```

Comment: `$files_data[field] = value`

Comment: Does that add a new field with a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$files_data['yourFieldName'] = $yourValue;
array_walk($files_data, 'array_sanitize');

        $fields = '`'.implode('` , `', array_keys($files_data)).'`';
        $data = '\''.implode('\', \'',$files_data).'\'';

   mysqli_query($dbCon,"INSERT INTO users_info($fields) VALUES ($data) ");
```

Comment: @Sudi. If that worked, please add a point and check the answer as correct.